# why pymqi won't install if MQ client is installed on centos 7?

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am trying to install pymqi using docker. The mq client is installed on /opt/mqm.
The output I get is the following one. It says there is a library missing, called cmqc.h

Can you tell me what is wrong ?

This is a linux CENTOS 7. The mq client is version 9.x

First the confirmation I've the libs:

```
ls /opt/mqm/lib64

 ---> Running in 7590f44ed84d

amqlcelp

amqlcelp_r

libimqb23gl_r.so.4.1

libimqc23gl.so

libimqc23gl.so.4.1

libimqc23gl_r.so

libimqc23gl_r.so.4.1

libmqcxa.so

libmqcxa64.so

libmqcxa64_r.so

libmqcxa_r.so

libmqdc.so

libmqdc_r.so

libmqe.so

libmqe_r.so

libmqecs.so

libmqecs_r.so

libmqic.so

libmqic_r.so

libmqicb.so

libmqicb_r.so

libmqiz.so

libmqiz_r.so

libmqjx_r.so

libmqjxx_r.so

libmqm.so

libmqm_r.so

libmqmcs.so

libmqmcs_r.so

libmqmzse.so

libmqxzu.so

libmqxzu_r.so


libmqz.so

libmqz_r.so

libmqzsd.so

libmqzsd_r.so
```

and then the error log:

```
Step 14/14 : RUN pip install pymqi


 ---> Running in b3fe8af64752

Collecting pymqi

  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/33/c567a624e7c09a5ab50352dc2aa586fbdf75fbe185d55a2d1d027fe685b2/pymqi-1.12.0.tar.gz (75kB)

Installing collected packages: pymqi

  Running setup.py install for pymqi: started

    Running setup.py install for pymqi: finished with status 'error'

    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-P1MQ9K/pymqi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zRYa70-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

    Building PyMQI client mode 64bits

    Using library_dirs:`['/opt/mqm/lib64']`, include:`['/opt/mqm/inc']`, libraries:`['mqic_r']`

    running install

    running build

    running build_py

    creating build

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7

    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    copying code/pymqi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    copying code/pymqi/CMQC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    copying code/pymqi/CMQCFC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    copying code/pymqi/CMQXC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    copying code/pymqi/CMQZC.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    copying code/pymqi/const.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/pymqi

    running build_ext

    building 'pymqi.pymqe' extension

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/code

    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/code/pymqi

    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYQMI_BINDINGS_MODE_BUILD=0 -I/opt/mqm/inc -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c code/pymqi/pymqe.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/code/pymqi/pymqe.o

    code/pymqi/pymqe.c:78:18: fatal error: cmqc.h: No such file or directory

     #include <cmqc.h>

                      ^

    compilation terminated.

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: It does not appear to be complaining about a library, It says the header file "cmqc.h" is missing. If you list the files in /opt/mqm/inc what do you see?

Comment: If you are using the redist client,  headers are not included until v9.2.  9.1 and lower redist clients do not include header files.